# Trouble loading/syncing Ziplist calendar into Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, upload

I'm having trouble loading/syncing my Ziplist calendar onto my Google Calendar. It loads from the URL, but doesn't upload the complete calendar.

Also, how long does it take to synchronise any updates I make on the Ziplist calendar?

This is the URL I'm using:
`webcal://www.ziplist.com/recipes/meal_calendar/49b31390-64b3-012f-a5da-123139276369/meals.ics?force_partner_content=ziplist`

Answer (score 1):

I actually helped build this feature -- if there was anything we could do to speed it up we would. Unfortunately there isn't much we can do, it requires Google to go update the calendar with the new event details.

They have a bot that crawls the webcal feeds and will index them. I have noticed events not showing up until the next day in some cases. However it normally updates within a few hours. I did check the URL you are using and it seems to be working just fine, so I suspect it is just a matter of waiting for Google calendar to update the events for you.